# PHP 5 not loading mysqli or mysqli not functioning?

Tags: php, unix, mysqli

I have a Solaris 10 server running `PHP 5.3.27`.  I've been trying to get `mysqli` to work but am not having any luck.

If I run `'php -m'` I do see `mysqli` in that list.  However, if I use a `'phpinfo()'` script I do not see `mysqli` anywhere on the page.

I also get an error if I try to use `mysqli` functions:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function `mysqli_connect()`
```

I also tried manually adding `mysqli.so` to my `php.ini` file and restarting `httpd` but nothing changed (I verified `mysqli.so` is present in the extensions directory).

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: PHP 5.3 was end-of-lifed over three years ago. It's dangerously insecure and irresponsible to run in production. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: I have to keep it for now.  I need to be able to convert all my scripts to be able to use mysqli so they will be compatible with PHP7+.  I need to get mysqli working on PHP5 so I can do that without extended downtime for users.

Comment: Can't you pull the code down locally and develop it on 7 then push to prod once your server version is upgraded?

Comment: The server isnt accessible to the internet so the PHP version isnt a big issue for us right now.  My development environment is on there as well so in either case, I need a working mysqli to proceed.